# Jquery - access to all instances of a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, find-occurrences

I'm developing a jquery plugin "`myPlugin`" who does some graphic things. It's working good and I'm happy about it.

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(params) {
        /* some code */
        $(this).focus(function() {
            /* draw things */
        });
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

I call it like so : `$("#foo").myPlugin();`

All is working good : every-time the element get the focus, the plugin is triggered, drawing some cool things. The plugin contain a private function `end` that I can eventually access from outside through a function `close`

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(params) {
        /* some code */
        $(this).focus(function() {
            /* draw things */
        });
        function end(){
            /* destroy the draw */
        }
        return{
             close: function() { end(); }
        }
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

This function allows me to close the plugin "from outside".

```
var bar = $("#foo").myPlugin();    // create the graphic
bar.close();                       // destroy the graphic for this element
```

All still works good ! But now, I have a problem : I would like to access to all plugins. Let's say that I need to create a random number of it :

```
var bar1 = $("#foo1").myPlugin();
var bar2 = $("#foo2").myPlugin();
var bar3 = $("#foo3").myPlugin();
```

I would like that when an element get the focus (and start the draw), it does destroy all the other existing ones :

when :

```
$("#foo1").focus();    // make the draw
```

it does too :

```
bar2.close();    // destroy an eventual draw of #foo2
bar3.close();    // destroy an eventual draw of #foo3
```

And here ... I'm blocked. **How to access to all occurs of my plugin ?** I was thinking to save somewhere all the var names (bar1, bar2, bar3, ...), to access to it, but I can't get them through the plugin. Or eventually create a second intermediary plugin that will launch the `myPlugin` and store the names, ... I'm confused. Any ideas ?

Cheers <3

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do something like this

(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(params) {
        /* some code */
        $(this).focus(function() {
        //clear previous things
        $('.myplugin').parent().remove()// or remove your markings
        //append
        $(this).append('<div class=".myplugin"></div>')
        /* draw things */
        });
        function end(){
            /* destroy the draw */
        }
        return{
             close: function() { end(); }
        }
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

Clear all such div parents or markers when u focus
add a temp div to your plugin  id

Comment: This idea is quite cool, but (what I did not mentioned), `myPlugin` contain some private var that I have to reset. It's not only graphic. I guess with couple of workaround, I can pass through ...